# Hyperledger Fabric - backup and restore

Tags: backup, hyperledger-fabric, restore

I'm using Hyperledger Fabric and now I'm trying to make a backup of the current situation and restore it on a different computer.

I'm following the procedure found in [hyperledger-fabric-backup-and-restore](https://medium.com/@jariarud/hyperledger-fabric-backup-and-restore-3263561e259e).
The main steps being:

1. Copy the crypto-config and the channel-artifacts directory
2. Copy the content of all peers and orderer containers
3. Modify the docker-compose.yaml to link containers volumes to the local directory where I have the backup copy.

Yet it's not working properly in my case: when I restart the network with `./byfn.hs up` I first have all the containers correctly up and running then, whatever operation I try and execute on the channel (`peer channel create`, `peer channel join`, `peer channel update`) fails with error:

```
Error: got unexpected status: BAD_REQUEST -- error applying config update to existing channel 'mychannel': error authorizing update: error validating ReadSet: proposed update requires that key [Group]  /Channel/Application be at version 0, but it is currently at version 1
```

Is there anything I should do which is not mentioned on [hyperledger-fabric-backup-and-restore](https://medium.com/@jariarud/hyperledger-fabric-backup-and-restore-3263561e259e) ?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error while trying to create a channel. Turning the "network down" and then "network up" solved my problem.